# Elasticsearch "illegal_argument_exception" when trying to search by string type

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch

I've setup Elasticsearch on magento and when trying to search by any string I'm getting an error

```
illegal_argument_exception: Invalid format: "search string"
```

I found out that when I removed all ***datetime*** attribute I've got another error

```
number_format_exception: For input string: "search string"
```

And I understand that now something wrong with ***int*** type attributes

When I'm searching by ***int*** everything is ok, result is there.

My suggestion - Elasticsearch created incorrect mapping (I didn't created it by hand it was done automatically after reindex products) but I wonder how to check this to be sure. Or have I ability to setup my own mapping.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely one of your int or decimal attributes is searchable.
Try to find them by using the following SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM eav_attribute e
LEFT JOIN catalog_eav_attribute cea ON e.attribute_id = cea.attribute_id
WHERE e.backend_type = 'decimal'
AND cea.is_searchable = 1
AND e.frontend_input != 'price';
```

If you find decimal attribute which is searchable try to make it as Not Searchable

- Go to admin -> store -> attributes -> product -> find the attribute
- Edit attribute and make it NOT Searchable
- Run full reindex php bin/magento index:reinde catalogsearch_fulltext

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with search string. With ES 2.4.6.I solved it change property of an attribute datetype to NOT use in search. I saw that there is an issue with date maping (when searching by string)

Answer (score 0):

This issue may occurs when you are using an older version of Elastic search. For example Magento 2.3 comes with Elasticsearch and Elasticsearch 5.0+ versions. You must have elasticsearch 5 installed as engine and select the Elasticsearch 5.0+ as search engine in Magento admin.

Furthermore as of time of writing I have found out that Elasticsearch 6 doesn't cope well with Magento. Elasticsearch 5 is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check the detail and fix shared by the Magento support here - https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360027356612-Elasticsearch-5-is-configured-but-search-page-does-not-load-with-Fielddata-is-disabled-error